# Routes working fine on local but not in Production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am currently trying to get my Ruby on Rails application running in a production environment. It is working fine but when I added a route under a nested namespace it is giving me error saying

> ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant Agent::Clients::AccountController)

**This routes are working fine on my local machine**, The route looks like this

```
namespace :agent do
root                     :to => redirect('url')
match 'dashboard',       :to => 'dashboard#index'
match 'account',         :to => 'account#edit'
match 'account/update',  :to => 'account#update'

namespace :clients do
  root              :to => redirect('url')

**# This part I added and is giving routing error**   
  match 'accounts/invite', :to => 'clients/account#invite'
  match 'accounts/sendinvite', :to => 'clients/account#send_invitation'
```

My rake routes giving the routes properly.
Any suggestions how to fix this issue ?

Comment: Do you have a controller called Agent::Clients::AccountController in: app/controllers/agent/clients/account_controller.rb

Comment: maybe an issue with pluralization: `clients/accounts#invite` vs `clients/account#invite` etc. check that your controller is named what you think it should be named

Comment: Have you got `end` at the end of your namespace blocks?

Comment: Yes I do have this controller but the name is accounts_controller (please mark s) on the path you have mentioned and I have another  controller named account_controller at app/controller/agent/account_controller.

Comment: @Edward yes I do ended the namespace block .

Comment: @Brian my action is written in the account_controller and the path is  app/controller/agent/account_controller

Comment: I did a monkey path for now to solve the issue I have created two separate routes outside the name space and hard coded the path of the controller/action and surprisingly it worked.

Answer (score 0):

So you either want to do

```
match 'accounts/invite', :to => 'clients/accounts#invite'
match 'accounts/sendinvite', :to => 'clients/accounts#send_invitation'
```

Or

```
match 'accounts/invite', :to => 'agent/account#invite'
match 'accounts/sendinvite', :to => 'agent/account#send_invitation'
```

Comment: I did a monkey path for now to solve the issue I have created two separate routes outside the name space and hard coded the path of the controller/action and surprisingly it worked.